# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Working on something where I need to generate 1000 random elements, then also generate a single random element called "searched value" then pass it through binary search and print weather the "searched value" was found or not... but getting an error

Code:

```
def binarySearch(item_list,item):
    first = 0
    last = len(item_list)-1
    found = False
    while( first<=last and not found):
        mid = (first + last)//2
        if item_list[mid] == item :
            found = True
        else:
            if item < item_list[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1
    return found

arr = [random.randrange(9999) for x in range(1000)]
searched_value = [random.randrange(0,1000)]
print(binarySearch(arr, searched_value))
```

Errors:

```
line 19, in <module>
    print(binarySearch(arr, searched_value))

line 11, in binarySearch
    if item < item_list[mid]:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: `searched_value` is a **list**.

Comment: Get rid of the square brackets when you assign to `searched_value`.

Comment: Hint: try to understand the error message. Which of those is a `list` and which is an `int`? Do you want them to be `list` or `int`? Why is the type not as you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code here

```
searched_value = [random.randrange(0,1000)]
```

should be

```
searched_value = random.randrange(0, 1000)
```

As it is you are creating a list and not a random number

Answer (score 1):

```
searched_value = [random.randrange(0,1000)]
```

===>

```
searched_value = random.randrange(0,1000)
```

Because, searched_value was list but, item_listpmid] is int.

Comment: You and everyone else are awesome :)